# Bluetooth speakers work on Windows but not Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth

My device, a Sony SRSX55, works when I'm booted into Windows 10, but when I'm in Ubuntu it pairs and sees the device but will not connect. I've tried many many things I found on line, but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1298831/edit) your question and add specifics as to what you have tried so that we are not guessing or giving you things to try that you have already tried.  Thank you!

Comment: were you able to make it work? For my Nothing Ear (1) Ubuntu is not detecting as audio device. But other bluetooth audio devices work fine.